# Detecting "value" of input text field after a keydown event in the text field?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, keydown

My site has an input box, which has a `onkeydown` event that merely alerts the value of the input box.

Unfortunately the value of the input does not include the changes due to the key being pressed.

For example for this input box:

```
<input onkeydown="alert(this.value)" type="text" value="cow" />
```

The default value is "cow". When you press the key <kbd>s</kbd> in the input, you get an `alert("cow")` instead of an `alert("cows")`. How can I make it `alert("cows")` **without using `onkeyup`**? I don't want to use `onkeyup` because it feels less responsive.

One partial solution is to detect the key pressed and then append it to the input's value, but this doesn't work in all cases such as if you have the text in the input highlighted and then you press a key.

Anyone have a complete solution to this problem?

Comment: alert($("input#recomendar_producto_email").val());

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**NOTE**: It's over a decade <sup>(!!)</sup> since I wrote this answer. The `input` event has become ubiquitous, and should be used instead of this hack.

<sup>What does keydown/keyup even mean for tablet and voice input devices?</sup>

---

The event handler only sees the content before the change is applied, because the `mousedown` and `input` events give you a chance to block the event before it gets to the field.

You can work around this limitation by giving the browser a chance to update the field's contents before grabbing its value - the simplest way is to use a small timeout before checking the value.

A minimal example is:

```
<input id="e"
    onkeydown="window.setTimeout( function(){ alert(e.value) }, 1)"
    type="text" value="cow" />
```

This sets a 1ms timeout that should happen after the keypress and keydown handlers have let the control change its value. If your monitor is refreshing at 60fps then you've got 16ms of wiggle room before it lags 2 frames.

---

A more complete example (which doesn't rely on [named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) would look like:

```js
var e = document.getElementById('e');
var out = document.getElementById('out');

e.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    out.value = event.target.value;
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="e" value="cow">
<input type="text" id="out" readonly>
```

When you run the above snippet, try some of the following:

- Put the cursor at the start and type
- Paste some content in the middle of the text box
- Select a bunch of text and type to replace it

Comment: thanks for the solution, but unfortunately this doesn't work in the case where the input is highlighted, and then a key is pressed. so for example if "cow" is highlighted and you press "s", it alerts "cows" when it should alert "s"

Comment: Updated to include a version that does work, at least in my browser.

Answer (score 10):

Please, try to use **oninput** event. 
Unlike *onkeydown*, *onkeypress* events this event updates control's value property.

```
<input id="txt1" value="cow" oninput="alert(this.value);" />
```

Comment: that's the best solution!

Answer (score 6):

Note that in newer browsers you'll be able to use the new HTML5 "input" event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.oninput) for this. Most non-IE browsers have supported this event for a long time (see compatibility table in the link); for IE it's version >/9 only unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

keyup/down events are handled differently in different browsers. The simple solution is to use a library like mootools, which will make them behave the same, deal with propagation and bubbling, and give you a standard "this" in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't do that with a standard input control unless you roll your own.

Answer (score -2):

Jquery is the optimal way of doing this. Please reference the following below:

```
let fieldText = $('#id');
let fieldVal = fieldText.val();

fieldText.on('keydown', function() {
   fieldVal.val();
});
```