# Change css when user starts typing in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website, and I want a `div` to go from `display: none;` to `display: block;` as soon as a user starts typing in the first input.

I know something about jquery, but I have no idea on how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are many good tutorials out there. You will probably need to read up on this and learn more if you plan on building a web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the keyup or keydown events :

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    if ( !$('div').is(':visible') ) $('div').show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/95K9R/)

Comment: It might be better to cache the selector for the element to show, otherwise you're creating a new jQuery object every time the user keys down on the field.

Comment: I'd also point out that on copy paste, or auto-fill, this will not catch it.  See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2826423/686036.  `oninput` in HTML 5 compatible browsers this would get these types of input.

Comment: @blo0p3r - The `input` event has really poor support and bugs all over the place, that's why noone uses it.

Comment: @adeneo Was not aware of this.  I'll look more into it.  Thanks!  Let's say it was so buggy and had more support, this would be a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: @blo0p3r - yes, if the `input` event was better supported and worked satisfactory it would be great. Today it's common to do `$('input').on('keyup paste change', function() { ...});` etc. to capture many events, the `input` event would make it easier, but as of today it barely works in the most modern browsers, so using it on a production website is not an option for most people.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){
    $('your_div').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keydown` event (`change` will only fire when the `input` looses focus):

```
var to_show = $('#your_div');

$('input').keydown(function() {  
    if(!to_show.is(':visible'))
    {
        to_show.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826423/686036, you would want to use the `HTML 5` syntax of `oninput`.  This would take care of auto-fill or right click paste functions.

You're input would look like this :

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

And the JavaScript :

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInput.addEventListener('input', myFunction(), true);
```

Or using JQuery if this is desired :

```
$('#myInput').bind('input', function() {
    alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

Now that `HTML 5` is a *W3C candidate recommendation*, it should/will be implement in most of the new releases of browsers, if it is not yet implemented.

Comment: The question had nothing to do with obtrusive JS of unobtrusive JS.  This was for an example for the use of `oninput`.  But will change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @BenM I disagree you should downvote on programming style that you don't "THINK" is best when this isn't specific topic - you should look at content of answer - comment on "specific answer" ie: using `oninput`.

Comment: Perhaps you do, but it's my prerogative unfortunately. Your answer is much better now, so I have rescinded the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use the change event with jquery :

```
    $('input').change(function() {
        $('#your-div').show();
    });
```

Comment: "if a user starts typing" sounds more like a `keypress` event. `change` only fires after focus is lost.