# I used onchange but the code is fired onblur plus the code is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Issues:

1. In Chrome and Firefox the code works but the event is fired `onblur` and I need it when typing **[solved by using `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`]**
2. This is not working in IE at all! **[solved by using Option object, see the update..]**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onchange="getLocations(this)" />
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" id="locationOpt"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getLocations(element) {
    var locations = Array("red","green","blue");
    var location_matched = [];

    for ( i in locations ){
            if(locations[i].search(element.value) > -1){
                    location_matched.push(locations[i]);    
            }
    }

    var html = "";
    for( i in location_matched){
            html += "<option value =\"" + i + "\">" + location_matched[i] + "</option>"; 
    }
    document.getElementById("locationOpt").innerHTML = html;
}
```

### *Update*

This the final working code:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="getLocations(this)" />
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" id="locationOpt"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getLocations(element) {
    var locations = Array("red","green","blue");
    var location_matched = [];

    for ( i in locations ){
            if(locations[i].search(element.value) > -1){
                    location_matched.push(locations[i]);    
            }
    }

var optionList = document.getElementById("locationOpt");

    //to remove all options
while (optionList.options.length) {
            optionList.remove (0);
    }

for( i in location_matched){
    // Option (text, value)
            var locationOption = new Option (location_matched[i], i);
            optionList.options.add (locationOption);
}
}
```

Comment: For text `input` elements, the `change` event is only triggered when the box looses focus and the value changed. If you want real time updates when the user types, you have to listen to one ore more of the key events.

Comment: onkeyup is better in my opinion

Comment: thank you Lucky, it works in every browser except IE?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onpropertychange for IE(this will also fire on cut/paste).
Furthermore: Instead of manipulating the innerHTML you should use [`new Option()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwrsipm.php) to create and insert the options.

Answer (score 1):

To detect changes as the user types, you'll have to use the `onkeypress` event. A similar question was already answered here: [Detecting "value" of input text field after a keydown event in the text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338483/detecting-value-of-input-text-field-after-a-keydown-event-in-the-text-field)

Comment: `onkeyup` is the solution. thanks for the link but why is this not working in IE?????

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Are you getting any JavaScript error messages?