# calling jQuery ajax functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Please bear with me; I've been battling with this for days.

I have a little bit of jQuery code in my jQuery(document).ready function as follows:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
          alert(response);
        });
    });
```

I have a text input field which I want sent to my Ajax function (using the Wordpress API)

```
    <input type="text" name="input" id=input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {send_message(this.value);}">
```

If the user presses the  key, the text is sent to the javascript 'send_message' function (below).

```
function send_message(value){
  data[txt]=value;
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
}
```

BAsically, I've added a 'txt' key/value pair to my data object and I now want this submitted to my ajax function.

The 'document ready' part works fine, but I can't get it to accept the changed data object.

As you can probably tell, I'm not following the logic behind the jQuery code very well.

Comment: I think your data object declaration is wrong, you should try with something like that : `var data = {txt: value};`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that the data object is initialised: var data = {
          action: 'chat_comms',
          nonce: '1f656a482b',
          id: 5
        };It's initialised in the root namespace.

Comment: Does `txt` have a value? Or are you trying to do `data["txt"]=value`?

Comment: txt is initialised as empty. I'm trying to set it with the contents of the text input that the user fills so that I can pass the text input value to the php function.

Comment: One possible reason why `this.value` is empty could be that it's not yet set when `onkeydown` is fired. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1338497/3305116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function send_message(value){

    if(!value){
        alert('value is empty');
    } 

    if(!data){
        alert('data is empty');
    }

    data.txt=value;

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       alert(response);
    });
}
```

if you check your console, you were probably getting txt is not defined you were missing the '' around them. Generally use the .dot notation for known object keys and save [] for dynamic keys if you believe in good practice.

Also you haven't mentioned what browser you are using...i cant swear this is current but firefox uses event.which instead of keycode...so:

```
 onkeydown="var code= event.which || event.keyCode; if (code == 13) {send_message(this.value);}"
```

**edit**

Solution for this instance.

You were enqueuing the js files on the hook 'enqueue_scripts' it should be 'admin_enqueue_scripts' and also specify it needs jQuery.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_chat_me_styles' ); //-->note changed hook!
```

I've also updated the js file to allow for console logs and the php file to allow for better feedback.

Jsfile - save as a new file name to rule out caching
http://pastebin.com/NyqGqhG0

Phpfile - note any notes...
http://pastebin.com/N7LQg0Zi

Comment: I've copied and pasted in your code and the data.txt entity remains an empty string, despite being assigned the value. The data appears to retain the values defined in the root namespace and altering them in the fuction doesn't appear to work.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm a little confused by the logic: if I remove the **jQuery(document).ready(function($)** part of the code (which, presumably, fires at the completion of document loading) the ajax post is no longer sent. It's as if the ajax.post in my **send_message** function is ignored.

Comment: PS, yes, I'm testing on Firefox.

Comment: I've amended the script:`<script>
var message='';
jQuery(document).ready(
  function($) {
    alert('Alert 1:'+message);//alert 1
    data={action: 'chat_comms', nonce: snonce, id: userid, txt: message};
    jQuery.post(
      ajaxurl,
      data,
      function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    );
  }
);
function send_message(value){
  alert('Alert 2:'+value);// alert 2
  message=value;
}
</script>`

Comment: I'm expecting that, when the **send_message** is run that the **message** variable is set to 'value'.

The **jQuery(document).ready** function appears to be called after send_message (I'm not sure why, but anyway), but the **message** variable is blank according to the alert 1, even if alert 2 shows it to have a value.

Comment: dave can you post your complete js code (edit the question above) where you set the variables for data etc and doc ready and send message. Also do you know how to check the console for errors (in chrome or firefox right click on the page (not a img) and go to inspect element and then click on console on the top ribbon of the pop up)

Comment: The entire contents of my js file:`var message_id=0;
var chatid=0;
var dest=0;
var chat_txt='';
var privacy=0;
var snonce='';
var userid=0;
var message='';
jQuery(document).ready(
  function($) {
    alert('message='+message);
    data={action: 'chat_comms', nonce: snonce, id: userid, txt: message};
    jQuery.post(
      ajaxurl,
      data,
      function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    );
  }
);
function send_message(value){
  alert(value);
  message=value;
}
function open_chat(thread){
  document.getElementById('initiate_chat').style.display='inline';
  return false;
}`

Comment: you are trying to set the txt value by changing the message variable? They are not bound together so you need to set data.txt= 'whatever'; See this code pen for an example. http://codepen.io/ambrosedheffernan/pen/LpYewr

Comment: I've copied in your codepen example verbatim using copy-and-paste: the txt field holds 'blank', irrespective of what is in the input field.

Comment: something missing here. That could never be the case with the code i provided. Can you post your current code (please do not use comments for this) and whats contained in your console. Where are you trying to get the value of txt? Is it server side? if so show that code also. Where do you define ajax url etc? Also if the js code is in a js script, it could be cached, change the name to make sure.

Comment: Incidentally, your assistance is much appreciated. Stackoverflow is complaining that I can't have an extended conversation in comments. Also the code is too long. I've cut and pasted your code. Verbatim. the site is a wordpress site and I've used this as a base method: http://www.paulund.co.uk/using-ajax-wordpress

Comment: I dont mind helping you but i've updated what needs to be checked to solve this. 100% the js code i gave you works, but the environment it is being posted into is unknown for me. I have only the code you posted and I have checked that for you. You have not answered the questions i need to know to solve this if that makes sense? Use http://pastebin.com/ for long code, but it shouldn't be that long?

Comment: Ok.1: the template is a widget here:http://pastebin.com/PFjut2y2. 2. The JS is called from my pluging php file here: http://pastebin.com/CHSRVbWM 3. ajaxurl defined in the file (#2). 4. as in (#2). 5.Variables set in the js file: http://pastebin.com/PBfv24fN 6. add_action in here: http://pastebin.com/CHSRVbWM . 7. There are no logs in the console data (except a 404 error for a missing image file).

Comment: Hi David, thanks very much for your help on this. It is much appreciated. I haven't had a chance to test it as I've been side tracked on another project, but I'll revert once I do. Thanks again.

Comment: I can't get it to work. The script fires ok, but the message remains 'blank'. Nothing I do seems to change it.

Comment: something up here.........it works for me can you set up  a url on the same server to test on?

Comment: actually i've just thought of something, try inserting data to the document object e.g. document.data= {} and change in the same way, document.data.txt= '';

Comment: Hi David, I've got it to change the message (it was a typo). Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: no problem, can you accept the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter in your function is not initialized. You should probably see a javascript error if you inspect your page using chrome or firefox.

Basically the data parameter in jquery's post function accepts either a serialized form query string or JSON string/object.

Also, please check the api: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Try below modified code:

```
function send_message(value){
    var data={txt:value};
      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });
    }
```

Comment: It is initialised in the root namespace.<script>
        var data = {
          action: \'chat_comms\',
          nonce: \''.$nonce.'\',
          id: '.$id.',
          txt: \'\'
        };
      </script>'; The 'txt' key is passed an empty string. If I use data={txt:value}; as you suggest, the 'txt' value remains an empty string.