# Getting the contents of a span to change as I change a number input

Tags: javascript

I had a more complicated form working a couple of days ago, but suddenly it stopped working and I'm rubbish at saving versions, so I've taken it right back to basics, and I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Am I using onInput incorrectly?

```
<input type="text" id="number-of-copies-value" onInput="quote()" value="500">
<span id="total-cost-value">0.00</span>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
function quote() {
            var totalcostvalue = document.getElementById("total-cost-value");
            var numberofcopiesvalue = document.getElementById("number-of-copies-value").value;
            var totalcost = (+numberofcopiesvalue);

            totalcostvalue.innerHTML=totalcost.toFixed(2);

        }

        quote();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tod0wusv/1/

Comment: interestingly this works

https://jsfiddle.net/4jc0cb6a/

Comment: is it? The link I posted works for me on both chrome and firefox

https://jsfiddle.net/4jc0cb6a/

Comment: you didn't have the link when I said it didn't work :p

Comment: the issue with @TimGreen fiddle is where the javascript is loaded - put it "in head" and his works too -except for the initial quote(); call

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML expects the `quote()` function to be globally available. Make sure that is the case.

If I change your fiddle to have `quote()` available on global window object like,

```
window.quote = function quote() {
    // ...
};
```

the fiddle starts working again.

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tod0wusv/4/)**

If I create a local HTML file with your content, it works right away, which makes sense since `quote()` is defined on global scope.

Looks like JSfiddle executes the JavaScript in a function scope which breaks your `quote()` call.

Comment: yeah, in the jsfiddle javascript pane, click on the settings (cog icon) for javascirpt and change the "load type" to either of the "no wrap" options and this should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about browser compatibility I would suggest using the onkeydown event with a setTimeout function as described here [Detecting "value" of input text field after a keydown event in the text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338483)

To make this work in JSFiddle, change the javascript "load type" setting in your JavaScript settings to one of the "no wrap" options.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="number-of-copies-value" onkeydown="window.setTimeout(function() { quote(); }, 1)" value="500">
<span id="total-cost-value">0.00</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function quote() {
    var totalcostvalue = document.getElementById("total-cost-value");
    var numberofcopiesvalue = document.getElementById("number-of-copies-value").value;
    var totalcost = (+numberofcopiesvalue);
    totalcostvalue.innerHTML = totalcost.toFixed(2);

}

quote();
```

I've updated your JSFiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/tod0wusv/6/